# The Content-Security-Policy directive 'child-src' is implemented behind a flag which is currently disabled

Tags: cordova, content-security-policy

**The Content-Security-Policy directive 'child-src' is implemented behind a flag which is currently disabled.**

This the error showing when I am trying to build a cordova app .

I am using the meta for  overcoming  it

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob: filesystem: ws: gap: cdvfile: https://ssl.gstatic.com *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; child-src *;" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It's coming from [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/experimental/chromium/blink/+/2a7b86175aed02e9bf8a1475a42150ff31e4d6bf/Source/core/frame/csp/ContentSecurityPolicy.cpp#757) and because the name of the method is `reportUnsupportedDirective()` my guess would be that the directive is parsed as such but as the error indicates some flag must be switched to really activate it.

What I think is the most likely case: it is detected but not implemented yet. At least [this method over here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master/Source/core/frame/csp/CSPDirectiveList.cpp#220) does not mention my particular case that I face right now: `worker-src`.

The only call I found so far is from [this piece of code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master/Source/core/frame/csp/CSPDirectiveList.cpp#455).

Everything above reverse-engineered, so take it with a grain of salt.